# SQL - Managing wide and long format

Tags: sql, pivot, unpivot

I am trying to achieve the following challenge but I am not sure how to tackle it.

I have a table called "salesman_data" with 2 columns. Each columns represents a salesman (e.g. *salesman_id_1* and *salesman_id_2*). Each column contains data about products which have been sold by the corresponding salesman. The data stored is the product ID. For instance, the salesman *salesman_id_1* sold products whose ID are *123*, *456*, *789*, etc. The same applies for *salesman_id_2*. The table is the following:

**Table salesman_data**

| salesman_id_1 | salesman_id_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 321 |
| 456 | 654 |
| 789 | 987 |
| ... | ... |

I have to calculate the sales ratio. The ratio is defined as *(nb of product sold by the salesman) / (total nb product sold by everyone).* The required output for the answer is each salesman with their sales ratio. Then ordering data by salesman id. In my understanding, the output should look like this:

| salesman_id | ratio |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30.1 |
| 2 | 69.9 |

Since the original table does not allow me to sort data by salesman id, I would need to create an entire new table beforehand. I was thinking about doing this:

- Create a new table
- Calculate the ratio
- Insert the ratio into the newly created table
- Query the data from the new table

I do not know if my process is the most efficient. What do you guys think ?

Comment: which dbm are you using? unpivot syntax is very specific.

Comment: I am using sqlite. I think there is no "pivot" function for that right ?